# Preserve Ripple effect over UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

I want to preserve Ripple effect on my UIImageView. I know we can animate image for ripple effect , but preserve. In other words I want a rippled image.

I know we can animate image using

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:25.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition) 110 forView:imgRipple cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But it animates , doesn't keep the ripple. I think we can get rippled image if we Pause or Stop animation before it ends. Is it possible? how can we Pause or Stop **UIView Animation**?

If there is any alternate to this trick ,kindly mention it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my solution,

used this code

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [imgRipple.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
     imgRipple.layer.speed = 0.0;
     imgRipple.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```

and it paused

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it gives you what you want, but you can stop animations using those:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[CATransaction begin];
[myView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[CATransaction commit];
```

You can get the current state before stopping animation using presentationLayer:

```
CALayer* myPreLayer = [myView.layer presentationLayer];
CATransform3D currentTransform = [myPreLayer transform];
//if you need some specific info, you can use key-value pairs
float currentAngle = [[myPreLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Sorry , it stops the Animation instead of Pausing it. on call it resets image to its original state.

Comment: You can get the current state from presentationLayer, and set it manually.

Comment: presentationLayer , is it a property ? How to access it , any idea ?

Comment: Thanks @erkanyildiz for your help. But I got my solution from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

swift 5

Imageview set ripple animation its working fine......

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.bounds.width / 2
        self.animateImage()

    }
    func animateImage() {
            addRippleEffect(to: viewAnimation)
        }

        func addRippleEffect(to referenceView: UIView) {
            /*! Creates a circular path around the view*/
            let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: referenceView.bounds.size.width, height: referenceView.bounds.size.height))
            /*! Position where the shape layer should be */
            let shapePosition = CGPoint(x: referenceView.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: referenceView.bounds.size.height / 2.0)
            let rippleShape = CAShapeLayer()
            rippleShape.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: referenceView.bounds.size.width, height: referenceView.bounds.size.height)
            rippleShape.path = path.cgPath
            rippleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            rippleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            rippleShape.lineWidth = 5
            rippleShape.position = shapePosition
            rippleShape.opacity = 0

            /*! Add the ripple layer as the sublayer of the reference view */
            referenceView.layer.addSublayer(rippleShape)
            /*! Create scale animation of the ripples */
            let scaleAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
            scaleAnim.fromValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
            scaleAnim.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 1))
            /*! Create animation for opacity of the ripples */
            let opacityAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            opacityAnim.fromValue = 1
            opacityAnim.toValue = 0
            /*! Group the opacity and scale animations */
            let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
            animation.animations = [scaleAnim, opacityAnim]
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
            animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(1.0)
            animation.repeatCount = .infinity
            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
            rippleShape.add(animation, forKey: "rippleEffect")
        }
```