# how to perform Bump Distortion in ios 5.0?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-image

i need to perform Bump Distortion in **ios 5.0**...
my xcode doesn't show any error and also i am not get any output ...
while trace and print the **Bump filter** instance it prints the null value...

any idea about that...

*some of the post shows that was not work in ios 5.0,*
any other way is there to perform the Bump Distortion...

Thanks in advance....

Regards,

Spynet

My code...

```
context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
     CIFilter *bumpDistortion = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBumpDistortion"];
     [bumpDistortion setValue:ciimage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
     [bumpDistortion setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:200 Y:150] forKey:@"inputCenter"];
     [bumpDistortion setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
     [bumpDistortion setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0] forKey:@"inputScale"];

    CIImage *imageOutput = [bumpDistortion outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:imageOutput fromRect:[imageOutput extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    [self.imageView setImage:newImg];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As omz points out, this particular Core Image filter is missing as of iOS 5.1.

However, you can easily do this using my [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework and the GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter:

[image: Bump distortion]

For processing a UIImage, and getting a UIImage result, you'd use code like the following:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter alloc] init];
UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [stillImageFilter imageByFilteringImage:inputImage];
```

You can also do this on live video or prerecorded movies in realtime.

I show a few other distortions you can perform with this framework in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896856/19679).

Comment: where can i get GPUImage framework i need to perform the similar functionality?

Comment: @Spynet - Did you try the link above? https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage You can grab the framework, along with examples that demonstrate this, from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryDistortionEffect]` will show you that distortion filters (such as `CIBumpDistortion`) aren't available at all on iOS.

You can use the same method with `kCICategoryBuiltIn` to get a list of all filters that are available.