# iOS image retouching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

im trying to find out a way to retouch an face picture.

the way i want to retouch is make the eye a little bit bigger.

anyone know a library/framework for iOS which might be useful for it?

Comment: hi please refer see this post....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229645/how-to-perform-bump-distortion-in-ios-5-0

Comment: some technical word is there use man....(bumb effect)

Comment: @Spynet omg thx!!!!! this was the thing i was looking for :D:D:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Image might help with detecting eyes on a face.

See http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/ for example!