# How to add Bump Filter effect on UIImage in iPhone SDK - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to add Bump filter effect on UIImage in iphone SDk.  I am trying to implement using kernel values and convolve effect, but it gives very huge bump effect i need some small bump effect on image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting 5.1 and later you can find it in `Core Image` if you need to deploy to lower target you can use the awesome GPUImage framework from Brad.
Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229645/how-to-perform-bump-distortion-in-ios-5-0) to have more details about both.