# How to drag portion of image to make only that part stretch in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-image

I want to drag a particular portion of a image to stretch as follow.

[image]

I have checked [apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBumpDistortionLinear) as this is available in iOS 6. But I want to implement this in iOS 5. `CIBumpDistortionLinear`.

Please provide any solution for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Please provide any solution for it.` :)

Comment: i think this link can work for you.

[Link Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9896856/1111384

Comment: you found any solution? i have same problem